# Get IP address and date from log file with preg_match.

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a log file like blow that contains user login dates :

```
Date:2014-03-19 21:38:48 IP:127.0.0.1 Request:asdasd URL:127.0.0.1:1990/anti_attack/anti-bruteforce.php?pass=asdasd USERAGENT:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
```

I get list of current IP address logins with :

```
preg_match("#\b(IP:".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].")\b#", $sessions,$sessions1);
```

The result is :

```
Array ( [0] => IP:127.0.0.1 [1] => IP:127.0.0.1 )
```

It's not the result that I need. I need all requests that send in current minute.
for example if current date is `2014-03-19 21:38:48` i need all requests by current ip address `($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])` that send in `2014-03-19 21:38` and result must be like :

```
Array ( [0] => Date:2014-03-19 21:38:28 IP:127.0.0.1[1] =>Date:2014-03-19 21:38:40 IP:127.0.0.1 [2] =>Date:2014-03-19 21:38:48 IP:127.0.0.1)
```

Comment: could you use substr function to get the date for the matching IP address and then maybe use additional logic on it:
http://us2.php.net/substr
This is based on the assumption that all entries in your log files are in same format (starting with the word Date etc.)

Comment: Did you try constructing a regular expression that included the current date/time?  What issues did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used this :

```
$sessions=file_get_contents('session.log');
$sessions=explode("\n",$sessions);
foreach($sessions as $tmp)
  if(strpos($tmp,date("Y-m-d H:i")) !== false && strpos($tmp,$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) !== false)
    $sessions1[]=$tmp;
```